# Error Messages reading clickable in Voice Over

Tags: html, error-handling, accessibility, wai-aria

I have a `<div>` to display error message & have given the attributes `aria-live="assertive"`. When the voice over reads, it reads "Error Message .clickable"

I want the Voice Over to read only the error message not "clickable".

The structure is something like this

```
<div id="fnErr" aria-live="assertive">
<form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error" htmlEscape="false"/>
</div>
<label id="fNlbl" for="fN">
<spring:message ..... />
</label>
<form:input aria-required="true" type="text" tabindex="0" path="firstName" maxlength="90"     id="fN" class="" cssErrorClass="" />
```

In the rendered HTML it comes out like:

```
<div errMsg>
<span>---error content-----</span>
</div>
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following techniques to suppress the `clickable`:

- Text input with `disabled` attribute

  ```
  <input type="text" disabled="disabled" maxlength="13"><spring:message .... /></input>
  ```
- Text input with `readonly` attribute

  ```
  <input type="text" readonly="readonly" maxlength="13"><spring:message .... /></input>
  ```

Answer (score -1):

As  is not clickable element, if you want to make it clickable then we need to add the role attribute in  element.

```
<div errMsg role="button">
<span>---error content-----</span>
</div>
```